# What SQL WHERE condition should I use to get to INSERT just one row of data from one table to another for specific date with highest time?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in AWS Redshift as below picture:

[image]

Below is the SQL query I am using to move data from one table to another. The issue happening is as you can see from table for one day there are multiple values with different time stamp and I just want one value for each day in the results table "test_dcm.mediacost_latest" . What condition should I use for the "date" so that SQL query just picks one value for each day?

```
INSERT INTO test_dcm.mediacost_latest (campaign, mediacost, recent_sdc_report_time)
SELECT campaign, mediacost, _sdc_report_time
FROM test_dcm_test_report
WHERE date='????????????';
```

Comment: *One value for each day*, which one, "the latest" row? Per campaign/mediacost/day?

Comment: for _sdc_report_time @dnoeth

Comment: Which is the expected result for the few rows you show and why?

Comment: @dnoeth The above few rows u can see for specific date there are like 2-3 values I want just one value for each day. I don't know how to condition the WHERE _sdc_report_time=???? statement for date.

Comment: *I want just one value for each day* Which one? The row with the lowest time or the highest time or just any row?

Comment: @dnoeth Ohh ok got you I want one with the highest time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to assign a ranking. This is based on Standard SQL, hopefully supported by Redshift as-is:

```
with cte as 
 (
    SELECT campaign, mediacost, _sdc_report_time
      ,row_number() -- rank each campaign per day
       over (partition by campaign, cast(_sdc_report_time as date)
             order by _sdc_report_time desc) as rn
    FROM test_dcm_test_report
 )
SELECT campaign, mediacost, _sdc_report_time
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Ok another issue came up what is happening is there are multiple Campaign too so above query is picking one row per day regardless of campaign. I need one row per day per campaign how will I achieve using above query?

Comment: The `partition by campaign` returns one row per campaign per day. Something else must be causing your issue.

Comment: How will I get like top 5 ranking rows instead of just one?

Comment: *top 5 ranking rows* - per campaign/day? Simply change to `where rn <= 5`

Comment: Also what condition will I give if i want to select all distinct " _sdc_report_time" per day instead of the highest "_sdc_report_time"

Comment: Are there multiple rows per _sdc_report_time or what do you mean by *all distinct "_sdc_report_time"*? You can add it to PARTITION BY and ORDER BY whatever you want.

Comment: What I want to do is there duplicate rows for time for example as you can see in the diagram 6/1/2020 11:00:35 PM is repeated twice. What I want to do is pick only one row for 6/1/2020 11:00:35 PM time after  ordering the rows. So the new table will have all the rows with distinct time for each day. Let me know if this makes sense or if possible we can chat to explain more :)

Comment: If there are only those three columns it's a simple SELECT DISTINCT campaign, mediacost, _sdc_report_time FROM test_dcm_test_report`, otherwise change the row_number to `partition by campaign, _sdc_report_time  order by _sdc_report_time`

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you can do what you want with `limit`:

```
SELECT campaign, mediacost, _sdc_report_time
FROM test_dcm_test_report
WHERE _sdc_report_time >= ? AND _sdc_report_time < ? + interval '1 day'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this is the error i am getting Invalid operation: bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 2;

Answer (score 1):

Is not to clear your question but if you are looking just one result for day you can use

```
LIMIT 1
```

After your date selection, but you might want to order the results before that or adding the in between days.

Comment: Yes what should be the WHERE condition I should use?